# Calling Nuxt JS static files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I try to call my css files that i have in static directory but i get an error message

```
/* style not found */
```

this is my own code

```
    mode: 'spa',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  server: {
    port: 8000, // default: 3000
    host: '0.0.0.0' // default: localhost
  },
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'static/css/theme/layout.css' }
    ]
  },
```

and i do `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this reason nuxt have it's own.
In your case :

```
css: [
  './static/css/theme/layout.css'
],
```

Comment: if you insall SASS or what so ever it's can be passed through the same CSS object

Comment: should i install something ?

Comment: how can i do for javascript since i have a file called test.js inside static folder also thanks

Comment: I hope you find out how to do it. JS can be passed through script exmp. : script: [{
        src: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js",
        type: "text/javascript"
      }]

Answer (score 1):

For Javascript it is

```
export default {
    ...
    head: {
        script: [{src: "/js/example.js"}]
    }
    ...
}
```